# C# HttpHandler Path and SSL

Tags: c#, ssl, iis-6, httphandler

I have an HttpHandler which resizes images and works great for JPG, GIF, and PNG.  The issue I am having is two fold.

1) If I try to navigate to a page with an image on it via SSL (https://...) then the lock doesn't appear in the title bar in IE or FF.  I have confirmed this is due to the image.  If I remove the handler the lock shows up.

2) I only want to resize images in a single folder.  I am specifying that folder in web.config via 
`<add verb="*" path="Uploads/Images/*.*" type="..."/>`
However in IIS6 I still need to map .jpg .gif and .png to asp_isapi.dll so regardless of my PATH in web.config all my images are being processed and breaking SSL

So either answer would help:

1) Why is my httphandler breaking ssl
2) How do I have an httphandler on IIS6 that only touches .jpg's (for example) in a partiular folder, not ALL .jpg's?

PLEASE HELP and thank you.

Jon

UPDATE 1

The idea of using .axhs sounds interesting but Im not sure exactly what you mean? Are you proposing renaming the images I want to process to .axhs or simply referring to them that that (ie img src=images/foo.axhs)? If I went this route, how do I tell the difference between jpg, gif, and png if they all have the same extension? Thanks

UPDATE 2

I am positive I am not using absolute paths to the images with "http://"

UPDATE 3

I've also read that possible a seperate web.config in my images directory could help as well, but I am not sure of that either...

PLEASE HELP, DEADLINE COMING QUICKLY :(

Comment: You could always use .axhs extension for the images and avoid all this nastiness.

Comment: Precisely what URLs are being used for the <img> tags?  You're certain they're not hardcoded with *http*?

Comment: Just a guess, but this link appears to have a resolution to a similar issue. http://www.gidforums.com/t-12283.html

Comment: Reason for your 2nd problem is that static content is registered to be served by IIS. So IIS will not pass those requests to ASP.NET runtime, so naturally, ASP.NET config does not come into play. IIS7 with its integrate pipeline allows to register handlers for all content types. You have few solutions here - 
1) As suggested by tster, use extension served by ASP.NET to your images from specific folder and then map your handler to that extension for that folder 
2) Write IIS Extension that would handle specific image requests